# For multiple choices, Select with multiple='multiple' will not align to device screen when it is in table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Say, I have a select menu which allows multiple checks, Which works absolutely fine,

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
     <td>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="select-choice-10" class="select">Choose state(s):</label>
    <select name="select-choice-10" id="select-choice-10" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false"  style="overflow: hidden">
        <option>Choose options</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    </select>
</div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is... for my device screen i had set

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

but still when i select multiple items(say 10) the menu length expands to it's width to show all 10 selected items on it.. and this portion of screen looks partial on device..

I have tried for <-select style="overflow: hidden"> but still not working... please help me to solve this issue...